# How can I get full path of a directory (not a file) in developing ios

Tags: ios, nsstring, directory, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2d-x and I found it used pathForResource to get full path for a existing file. But I need to get the full path of a directory. If I simply pass "" to pathForResource, it will search and return the first file in that directory.

I cannot just take application directory and put it in front of relative path since I don't know if it's a relative one or already a full one.

I can trim the filename but I think that's a weird solution.

So is there any function in objective-c that works like pathForResource but don't really search for files... just return the directory name

BTW, I am using opendir functions in dirent.h. I found it won't work if I just pass a relative path, which was fine under windows.

Comment: you want to get path of directory from Bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DirectoryName"];
NSLog(@"%@", sourcePath);
```